# How to repair pierced refrigerant line in chest freezer?

Tags: hvac, hole, copper-tubing

My idiot friend was screwing brackets inside an ice cream freezer with self-tapping screws, and one of the screws pierced a copper line containing refrigerant. Apparently it made a crazy hissing sound and super cold gas came out of the hole. It happened outside and nobody was injured or anything, just shocked.

I figured since I know how to sweat a copper joint, I could fix the tiny hole in the copper line, and then get an HVAC tech to refill the lost refrigerant.

The plan is to cut the section of pipe with the hole in it, slip on a coupler, and solder the joint.

I know I have to be extra careful to not get anything inside the copper line, but aside from that, does this seem doable?

Also, which kind of solder should I use (60/40?), or should this be brazed?

Comment: Is this an expressive freezer (not a typical consumer freezer)?  If not, it might be cheaper to replace than to repair.

Comment: Yes, it's an ice cream display cabinet. Truthfully, though, the internals and the chassis are basically the same as your typical chest freezer, only the top part has glass on all sides and a swivel door for serving. It could actually be cheaper to find a used chest freezer and replace the lid with the aforementioned glass lid...mmh....for the sake of knowledge, any info on the type of solder used for refrigerant copper lines?

Comment: Don't even bother soldering it yourself.  If you're going to hire somebody to test it and charge it, it's not worth your time or money to try the repair yourself. Not to mention, if you mess up the repair, who ever you hire will just have to fix it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd vote for having the service guy fix the pipe. He has a bag of tools and couplers all the right size (you won't find what you need at Home Depot), and will have done this kind of thing a couple of hundred times. Your main expense will be the service call and the gas, they might not even charge for the 5 minute repair.

Don't touch it with solder - solder requires flux, and doing both a decent job on the joint and not polluting the inner works is rather difficult. The service guy will know how to do it and/or have flux that won't damage anything.

Is idiot friend going to man up and pay the bill?

Make sure you call a commercial company. It may look like a domestic fridge on the inside, but there may be enough differences to be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to pay and HVAC tech to refill the system for you, then why not have them do the copper repair, too? But why an HVAC tech? Call a refrigerator repair company.

Comment: You're probably right, the cost of them fixing the little hole is probably not much compared to the cost of refilling the system. I will make the cuts in the panel though, that will save them some time.